# Value sent to text box is getting defaulted to zero

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Whenever I am sending values to a text box that takes numeric only using selenium its getting defaulted to zero.

```
WebElement installmentAmount = driver.findElement(By.id("InstallmentAmount"));
installmentAmount.sendKeys("1000");
```

I have written above code.

Comment: Please try : driver.findElement(By.id("InstallmentAmount"))sendKeys("1000");

Comment: Is the site Publicly available?

Comment: first try to `clear()` the box then `sendKeys()`

Comment: Thanks for help guy it was sync issue used Thread.sleep()